# Integral calculation: $\int_0^1 (x-\sqrt{x}+\sqrt[3]{x}-\sqrt[4]{x}+\cdots) \, dx$

Tags: calculus, sequences-and-series, definite-integrals

$$K=\int_0^1 (x-\sqrt{x}+\sqrt[3]{x}-\sqrt[4]{x}+\cdots) \, dx$$

I'm looking for an exact solution for this integral. Thank you very much.

Comment: For this to have any meaning it'd need to be that the expression between parentheses (the integrand) converges to a definite expression depending on $\;x\;$ ...

Comment: Show your work. What have tried about this problem?

Comment: $\lim_{n\to \infty}\sqrt[n]{x} = 1$ and the integrand cannot converge.

Comment: @Chiranjeev I don't know where to start

Comment: @MichaelHardy the resulting series does not converge.

Comment: The series $x-\sqrt{x}+\sqrt[3]{x}-\sqrt[4]{x}+\cdots$ does not converge unless $x=0$, the the terms do not approach $0$.  If you integrate term by term, you also get a series that can be seen not to converge.  Perhaps there is some "summation method" other than the simple one taught in high school, by which this can be considered to have some particular value.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If $x-\sqrt{x}+\sqrt[3]{x}-\sqrt[4]{x}+\cdots$ converges then $\lim\limits_{n\to\infty} \sqrt[n] x =0$.  But in fact $\lim\limits_{n\to\infty} \sqrt[n] x =1$, so the function to be integrated is not well defined in the usual sense.

An integral $\displaystyle \int(A+B+C+\cdots)$ can be written as $\displaystyle\int A + \int B+\int C+\cdots$ if there are only finitely many terms, but it doesn't always work with infinitely many terms, and one might wonder whether a convergent series would result in this case:
$$
\int_0^1 (x-\sqrt{x}+\sqrt[3]{x}-\sqrt[4]{x}+\cdots)\, dx = \frac 1 2 - \frac 2 3 + \frac 3 4 - \frac 4 5 + \cdots.
$$
But again, the absolute values of the terms approach $1$ rather than $0$, so the series diverges.

[There are non-standard "summation methods"](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Divergent_series) by which series that don't converge in the simple sense taught in high school have sums in another sense.  Whether any of those can be applied here I don't know.

Comment: I haven't run through the algebra, but Abel summation seems like a natural choice to try and make work here.

Comment: The Abel method produces $\ln(2) - 1/2$, since for $|t| < 1$, 
$$\sum_{n=1}^\infty (-t)^{n+1} \dfrac{n}{n+1} = \ln(t+1) - \dfrac{t}{t+1}$$

Comment: @RobertIsrael That works nicely for the post-integration series; I was wondering more about the integrand itself, though, where I don't think the math is quite as clear (and there might not be an elementary expression) - clearly the series $\sum_n(-t)^nx^{1/n}$ converges for $|t|\lt 1$ for all $x$, though. Presumably there's enough uniformity to know that we can interchange the limit and the integration regardless of the integrand function itself.

Comment: For any $|t| < 1$, Lebesgue dominated convergence lets you exchange sum and integral:  $\int_0^1 \sum_{n=1}^\infty (-t)^n x^{1/n}\; dx  = \sum_{n=1}^\infty \int_0^\infty (-t)^n x^{1/n}\; dx = \ln(t+1) - t/(t+1)$.

Comment: As for the Abel summability of $\sum_{n=1}^\infty (-1)^n x^{1/n}$, we have
$x^{1/n} = 1 + \ln(x)/n + g_n(x)$ where $g_n(x) = O(1/n^2)$, so 
the Abel summability value for this will be $-1/2 - \ln(2) \ln(x) + \sum_{n=1}^\infty g_n(x)$.

Answer (score 1):

$$x - x^{1/2} + x^{1/3} - \ldots = (-1)^{1+ 1} (x)^{1/1} + (-1)^{2+1} (x)^{1/2} + \ldots = \sum_{n=1}^{\infty} (-1)^{n+1} x^{1/n}$$

This series doesn't converge for $0 < x \le 1$. We can't integrate it.

**Edit:**

For $0 < x \le 1$:

$$\lim_{n \to \infty} \sup \{ (-1)^{n+1} x^{1/n} \}= 1 \neq 0$$

The series fails to converge (using the limit test).

Comment: Why not? You claim it - but does it not? Can you give proof?

Comment: Of course I can. Give me some time.

Answer (score 1):

$$\int_0^1 x^{1/n}dx=\frac{n}{n+1}$$ hence $$K=\sum_{n=1}^{\infty}(-1)^{n+1}\frac{n}{n+1}$$

you should be able to continue ...

Answer (score 0):

Given

$$
K = \int_0^1 ( x - \sqrt{x} + \sqrt[3]{x} - \sqrt[4]{x} + \cdots )
$$

Write this as

$$
K = - \int_0^1 \sum_{k=1}^\infty (-1)^k x^{1/k}
$$

Thus

$$
K = - \sum_{k=1}^\infty (-1)^k \int_0^1 x^{1/k} = \sum_{k=1}^\infty (-1)^k \left[ \frac{1}{1/k+1} x^{1/k+1} \right]_0^1
$$

So

$$
K = - \sum_{k=1}^\infty (-1)^k \frac{k}{1+k}
$$

We obtain

$$
K = \frac{1}{2} - \frac{2}{3} + \frac{3}{4} - \frac{4}{5} + \cdots
$$

or

$$
K = - \frac{1}{2 \cdot 3} - \frac{1}{4 \cdot 5} - \frac{1}{6 \cdot 7} - \cdots
$$

or

$$
K = - \frac{1}{6} - \frac{1}{20} - \frac{1}{42} - \cdots
$$

Which can be written as $\ln(2) - 1$, so

$$
\int_0^1 ( x - \sqrt{x} + \sqrt[3]{x} - \sqrt[4]{x} + \cdots ) = \ln(2) - 1
$$

Comment: You exchanged integral with the sum before establishing (uniform) convergence of the series.

Comment: Also the series $\sum (-1)^k \frac{k}{1+k}$ do not converge. It is alternating, but the general term do not go to zero as $k\to\infty$.

Comment: This is a very good example of when sum and integral signs can *not* be exchanged. The integral cannot be done as there is *not* a function there to integrate, to begin with.

Comment: Fun that others do the same and get votes up ;)

Comment: @Winther - it does converge...

As $\int_0^1 f(x) = \int_0^1 f(1-x)$, so we need to expand $(1-x)^a$ which can be written as a serie for $x<1$ - but the $x=1$ does not require expanding as it is zero...

Comment: @Timbuc - you can exchange the integral sign, for $\int_0^1 f(x) = \int_0^1 f(1-x)$ and all $\sqrt[n]{x}$ become $\sqrt[n]{1-x}$ and each $\sqrt[n]{1-x}$ can be written as a serie for $x<1$...

Comment: @johannesvalks I beg to difer: first, the integral isn't even well defined as the integrand is not even a function: it doesn't exist. Now, you can try some other summabilitiy methods, like Abel's, as said in other comments.

Answer (score 0):

However, if we interpret $x-\sqrt{x}+\sqrt[3]{x}-\sqrt[4]{x}+\ldots$ as $\sum_{n=1}^\infty\,\left(x^{\frac{1}{2n-1}}-x^{\frac{1}{2n}}\right)$, then this series converges uniformly on any interval $[\epsilon,1]$ for $\epsilon>0$.  Hence, the required integral would then be $\sum_{n=1}^\infty\,\left(\frac{2n-1}{2n}-\frac{2n}{2n+1}\right)=\sum_{n=1}^\infty\,\left(-\frac{1}{2n}+\frac{1}{2n+1}\right)=-1+\ln(2)$.